# The query result changes in remote and local database

Tags: db2, db2-luw

The below table is created in local database and remote databases.

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE1 ( EMP_ID INTEGER, EMP_NAME VARCHAR(10), EMP_DEPT VARCHAR(10) );
```

Insert the below rows in tables created in both the databases.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE1 (EMP_ID, EMP_NAME,EMP_DEPT)
VALUES (1,'A','IT'), (2,'B','IT'), (3,'C','SALES'), (4,'D','SALES'), (5,'E','ACCOUNTS'), (6,'F','ACCOUNTS'), (7,'G','HR'), (8,'H','HR');

COMMIT;
```

If i run the below query in local database of my system then the query result is correct.i.e it is returning all the rows in the table as the query exactly has to do. But the same query if i run in remote database then only 4 rows are returned,which is a wrong result.

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE1 WHERE (EMP_DEPT NOT IN ('IT','SALES') OR EMP_DEPT IN ('IT','SALES'));
```

**Can anyone suggest why the query behavior changes?**

Comment: Simply you can use `SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE1`.

Comment: Are you sure you're running the exact same query/datasets?  There's no reason for there to be different results (Well, barring some freak accident with old index statistics).  Which four rows are you getting back?  In particular, a pair of misplaced apostrophes (single quotes) could cause the given behavior.

Comment: Please post operating system, DB2 version with fix pack level for both local and remote databases.

Comment: EMP_ID EMP_NAME EMP_DEPT
1 A IT
2 B IT
3 C SALES
4 D SALES.Yes i am running the same script in both the database. Above mentioned are the four rows returned by the query in remote database.I am using DB2 express C 9.7 in local database with windows 7 OS and DB2 enterprise edition in Remote database.

Answer (score 0):

As per your query, you want to select all the records. Then simply you can use the following

```
SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE1
```

What is the purpose of this condition?

```
WHERE (EMP_DEPT NOT IN ('IT','SALES') OR EMP_DEPT IN ('IT','SALES'))
```

Comment: No..My concern is about the difference in results.Whatever the condition may be but the result should be same.But the query is giving different results.

Comment: DROP the table in remote and try again with this... Check whether you get all the records...

Comment: Tried as you suggested.But the result is still same.I tried in different editors TOAD and IBM data studio but the result is same with remote database.